# Como transformar uma String "Caiaaaque" para outra String "Caiaque"?

Tags: java, string

Eu to desenvolvendo um sisteminha onde o usuário digita uma palavra errada, e eu trocou uma ou outra letra dessa palavra para corrigir, somente pra fins de estudos mesmo, e eu tenho que percorrer toda a String e pegar um exemplo, o usuário digita Caiaaaque e eu tenho que percorrer essa string letra por letra e substituir o erro pelo correto ficando Caiaque.

O trecho do código ja está assim:

```
public String retornaPalavra(String palavra){

    //for pra percorrer a String
    for(int i; i<palavra.lenght()-1;i++){

        if(palavra.charAt(i)==palavra.charAt(i+1)){

            palavra = palavra.replaceFirst(palavra.charAt(i), '');

            i = i-1;

        }    

    }

    retorno = palavra;

}
```

Agora o problema é que se o usuário digita Caiaaaque por exemplo ele retira todos os 'a' ficando assim Cique. E quero retornar Caiaque.

Comment: Agora li que é para fins de estudo. Retirei o meu comentário questionando a eficiência do método.

Comment: Você simplificou o código antes de postar aqui, certo? Esse trecho acima nem compila... E mesmo resolvendo os erros de compilação, ele lança um `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` (por você tentar acessar o `i+1` sendo `i` o último índice da string. Problemas desse tipo poderiam ser evitados com um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Piovezan se for de maior eficiencia tb vale

Comment: @mgibsonbr sim eu simplifiquei mesmo, qto a esse erros ja estao sendo tratados pra nao dar os erros.

Comment: O problema é que não consigo reproduzir seu erro, então não sei qual a melhor forma de te ajudar (exceto fazendo pra você, o que imagino que não é o que você quer). [No ideone](https://ideone.com/1b12MG) o resultado que tive foi "Ciaaaque".

Comment: @mgibsonbr extamente, o erro resultante não é relevante, so quero saber como substituir os outros 'aaa' por 'a' sem interferir no primeiro.

Comment: Se o usuário digitar alguma palavra tipo google, que é correta, você irá incorretamente alterá-la para gogle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método [`replaceFirst`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) foi feito pra ser usado com expressões regulares, não com strings, e muito menos com caracteres. Por exemplo, se você fizer:

```
String s = "a..";
s.replaceFirst("" + s.charAt(1), "");
```

O resultado será `".."` (pois `.` é uma expressão regular que casa "qualquer coisa"). Tentar adaptar seu código para fazer o que você quer é infrutífero, a menos que você queira trabalhar de fato com expressões regulares[1].

Sendo assim, minha sugestão é evitar substituições, e sim usar o método [`substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) para pegar a string até o ponto que você está e juntar com a substring após o ponto que você quer retirar.

---

[1]: E se você *quer* trabalhar com expressões regulares, a maneira mais simples de fazer isso é através de *backreferences* (uma única linha de código faz todo o serviço):

```
palavra = palavra.replaceAll("(.)\1+", "$1");
```

[Exemplo](https://regex101.com/r/fU0wI9/1).